# Aptana syntax coloration for bash scripts

Tags: eclipse, bash, shell, plugins, aptana

I can't get my hands on any syntax coloring plugin to use with bash `.sh` files in Apatana.
I've seen this post :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167009/how-to-edit-bash-scripts-with-aptana

But it just speaks about Shell Script which doesn't seem to be a text editor but more an integrated terminal.

I have also tried [ShellEd](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/shelled/) but Aptana does not meet the requirements for the install (requires Eclipse Juno version 4.2.x and Aptana is based on 3.7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ShellEd is ready**

***Installation***

The installation of Shelled with all dependencies in Aptana Studio 3 is possible now.

1. [Download the Dynamic Language Toolkit V4.](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/dltk/downloads/drops/R4.0/R-4.0-201206120903/dltk-sdk-R-4.0-201206120903.zip)
2. Add the archive to your repo lis.
3. Add [Shelleds repo on Sourcforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/files/shelled/update/) to your repo list, too.
4. Install ShellEd.
5. Restart Aptana Studio 3.

***Customization***

Open

Preferences -Shell Script --> Syntax coloring

and adjust the elements colors to your selected theme.

PS: Don't forget to add shellEd as default editor for *.sh files in the File Associations dialogue.

Comment: Doesn't work with Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805

I can't install Dynamic Language Toolkit V4, either from the archive or from the update site...

Comment: That's right you have not to. Just add the arive to your repo list and than install shell ed with the url from step 3 That should fix it.

Comment: @horvan following these steps here's the error i get: Missing requirement: Dynamic Languages Toolkit Launching Core 4.0.0.201206120848 (org.eclipse.dltk.launching 4.0.0.201206120848) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: Try this one: Add the archive you download to your sources.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/dltk/downloads/drops/R5.0/R-5.0-201306060709/dltk-I-201306060709.zip

Comment: @horvan the problem was not coming from dltk but from that missing 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore 0.0.0''. I added http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/updates/releases/ to my update sites and got it working.

Comment: It would be good to add an explanation for #2 and #3 for those of us that don't know what adding to aptana repo list means